# asyncstorage + redux thunk + redux persist, callback on dispatch

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux-thunk

I am using [redux-thunk](https://github.com/gaearon/redux-thunk) in my react native app along with [AsyncStorage](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/asyncstorage.html) & [redux-persist](https://github.com/rt2zz/redux-persist). So naturally there is delay in changes state being taken effect after dispatching an action.

```js
import { compose, createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import { persistStore, autoRehydrate } from 'redux-persist';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import reducers from '../reducers';
import { AsyncStorage } from 'react-native';
import createLogger from 'redux-logger';

const logger = createLogger({
  predicate: () => process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development'
});

const middleWare = [ thunk, logger ];

const createStoreWithMiddleware = applyMiddleware(...middleWare)(createStore);

export function makeStore(onComplete :? () => void) {
  const store = autoRehydrate()(createStoreWithMiddleware)(reducers);
  persistStore(store, {
    storage: AsyncStorage
  }, onComplete);
  return store;
}

export default makeStore;
```

in my case

```js
console.log(this.props.counter); // 1
this.props.dispatch(incrementCounter());
console.log(this.props.counter); // still 1 ?
```

so what i need to do is add a [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) like callback on the dispatch function like

```js
this.props.dispatch(incrementCounter())
    .then(() => console.log(this.props.counter)); // 2
```

how can i accomplish this? i've used setTimeout but i don't think its a reliable option.

Answer (score 1):

You need to understand the basic behind flux.

Action=> Dispatch=> Store updates=> Subscribed modules are notified

In your case no timeout can work, you have to subscribe store to get notified on store update.

http://redux.js.org/docs/api/Store.html#subscribe